# How to properly shutdown log4j2

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2, application-shutdown

If one is not running inside a web application, what is the proper way to shutdown Log4j2?  I only see a noop LogManager.shutdown()

Answer (score 19):

There is no public API for this, but you can use

```
((LifeCycle) LogManager.getContext()).stop();
```

If you have an interest in having a public API for this, please vote for or add a comment here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-124

---

Update:

In Log4j 2.5 you can call `Configurator.shutdown()`. With Log4j 2.6 you can call `LogManager.shutdown()`.

Comment: And you should add `shutdownHook="disable"` to your log4j2.xml to disable the automatic shutdown hook.

Answer (score 9):

## Explanation and story behind

What Log4j 2 use internally is what they call a *ShutdownRegistrationStrategy*. It consist of a class that register one or many shutdown callback(s) that would be called at the appropriate time. They provide interface named [`ShutdownCallbackRegistry`](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/blob/master/log4j-core/src/main/java/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/util/ShutdownCallbackRegistry.java) and their default implementation named [`DefaultShutdownCallbackRegistry`](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/blob/master/log4j-core/src/main/java/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/util/DefaultShutdownCallbackRegistry.java). This implementation register itself as a shutdown hook to the JVM, with `Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook()`.

According to some issues on the Log4j 2 bug tracker ([LOG4J2-868](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-868) and [LOG4J2-658](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-658)), the right way would be to provide your own implementation of the `ShutdownCallbackRegistry` interface. Since there is no public API to shutdown Log4j 2, this is the only real and valid way to archive this.

## Proposed solution

So, what I did to fix this is that I implemented my own version of the `ShutdownCallbackRegistry` interface. It mostly does the same things the default implementation does, but instead of registering itself as a shutdown hook, it wait until it's invoked manually. That is made possible internally by keeping the instance of the object in a static field. You then only have to call single static method to launch the shutdown procedure, hence why I named it the [`StaticShutdownCallbackRegistry`](https://github.com/DjDCH/Log4j-StaticShutdown/blob/master/src/main/java/com/djdch/log4j/StaticShutdownCallbackRegistry.java).

You can find the complete solution and instructions on [GitHub/DjDCH/Log4j-StaticShutdown](https://github.com/DjDCH/Log4j-StaticShutdown) and use it in you own projects. Basically, at the end, you only have to do something like this in your application:

```
StaticShutdownCallbackRegistry.invoke();
```

*I can't say without any doubt that this is the perfect solution and that my implementation is perfect, but I tried to do it the right way (according to the none-existent documentation about it). I'll be glad to hear feedback from you, either if you find this solution appropriate or not.*

Comment: It looks like version 2.6 adds back a proper manual `.shutdown`, can anyone confirm? It does not really work here

Answer (score 9):

**Log4j-Web** library is the preferred way to properly clean-up resources in Web-application.

To enable it, add such a dependency to your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-web</artifactId>
    <version>${log4j2.version}</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

It will work 'out-of-the box' in Servlet 3.* environment.
If you're using older Servlet specification, details how to enable proper cleaning for log4j2 are available here:
https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/webapp.html

Comment: Note that the question is specifically about the case where "one is **not** running inside a web application" [emphasis mine].

Comment: you're right @ruakh anyway leaving the answer here because some people consider it useful for their cases....