# Spring @PreDestroy: No logging because Logback stops too soon

Tags: java, spring, logback, logback-classic

In my project, I am using Logback as logging facility. I have the following class

```
@Component
class Test {
    @PreDestroy
    public void destroy() {
        try {
            ...
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass()).error(e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I undeploy the servlet. When an exception occurs, Logback is not printing the message and stack trace. This is because Logback is cleaning up before the `destroy()` is called by Spring. When undeploying the servlet, this is the first (and last) log line:

```
15:46:19,084 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.servlet.LogbackServletContextListener@7957fe56 - About to stop ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext [default]
```

I verified that Logback stops first by adding a `System.out.println("...");` in the `destroy()`.

Is there any way to fix this?

My dependencies:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-framework-bom</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.1.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>99-empty</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.25</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-access</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jcl</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Please note that `spring-jcl` is used to route `commons-logging` to `slf4j` (which will route to `logback`). I am not using `jcl-over-slf4j`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring's @PreDestroy results in logging randomly not logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30426533/springs-predestroy-results-in-logging-randomly-not-logging)

Comment: I think it's indeed the same issue. Any idea how to disable the automatic shutdown from Logback (the `LogbackServletContextListener`) and manually shutdown Logback as late as possible? I am in a Tomcat/Spring environment.

Comment: Also duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17400136/how-to-log-within-shutdown-hooks-with-log4j2

Make sure you read the answer of user 'DjDCH'

Comment: That's about `log4j`, not `logback`/`slfj4j` though.

Comment: How about not registering LogbackServletContextListener in the web.xml, or WebAppInitializer, then it won't shutdown the logging.

Comment: It's registered automatically. All I am doing is adding Logback and slf4j to my dependencies and having a logback.xml in the classpath. I am not doing anything in the code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a [documented way](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html) to disable to disable the registering of the `LogbackServletContextListener`:

> You may disable the automatic the installation of
>   LogbackServletContextListener by setting a  named
>   logbackDisableServletContainerInitializer in your web-application's
>   web.xml file. Here is the relevant snippet.
>
> ```
> <web-app>
>     <context-param>
>         <param-name>logbackDisableServletContainerInitializer</param-name>
>         <param-value>true</param-value>
>     </context-param>
>     .... 
> </web-app>
> ```
>
> Note that logbackDisableServletContainerInitializer variable can also be set as a Java system property an OS environment variable. The most local setting has priority, i.e. web-app first, system property second and OS environment last.

I would imagine you'll probably want to write your own shutdown hook if this is the case and stop the [LoggerContext](https://github.com/qos-ch/logback/blob/master/logback-classic/src/main/java/ch/qos/logback/classic/servlet/LogbackServletContextListener.java)

Answer (score 3):

To pick up Dovmo's answer. It's all about ordering. I have the same issue on Tomcat 8.5.x. Bacially, the initializer does an `addListener`, you don't have any control over the listener. At shutdown, Tomcat reverse-iterates that list, picking the Logback listener first: Spring won't log anything.

A custom listener won't help because you cannot prepend it. What works for me on Tomcat is:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>ch.qos.logback.classic.servlet.LogbackServletContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<context-param>
    <param-name>logbackDisableServletContainerInitializer</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```