# Is there a way to destruct a bean after all other beans?

Tags: java, spring, spring-bean, servletcontextlistener, weblistener

This is a follow-up from [Spring @PreDestroy: No logging because Logback stops too soon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47184045/spring-predestroy-no-logging-because-logback-stops-too-soon).

In that question, user Dovmo gave a good suggestion on how to stop Logback from listening as a `ServletContainerInitializer` to self-destruct when the servlet is stopped. This works great.

I am now looking for a way to be able to destruct Logback as late as possible, preferable after every other bean has been destructed. In theory, I could add a `@DependsOn(logback-bean)` to every bean, but that would be very ugly. I also tried listening as a `@WebListener` and listen to the `ServletContextEvent` event, but these events seem to arrive before the first `@PreDestroy` of some random bean is called.

Is there a nicer way to execute code after all beans are destructed? That would solve the puzzle on forcing Logback to always log everything.